# Permission denied to a file in ~/.cache directory

Tags: permissions, home-directory, curl

When I set an output file in the home directory, the following `curl` command works. But when I use `~/.cache/mydir`, it returns "Permission error".

```
$ ls -al ~/.cache/tera
drwxrwxr-x  2 shinichi shinichi 4096 Jul 28 09:04 .
drwx------ 16 shinichi shinichi 4096 Jul 27 20:52 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 shinichi shinichi    0 Jul 28 09:04 radio_searches.json


$ curl -X POST -d tag=smooth http://all.api.radio-browser.info/json/stations/search -o $HOME/.cache/tera/radio_searches.json
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file 
Warning: /home/shinichi/.cache/tera/radio_searches.json: Permission denied
100    10    0     0  100    10      0      1  0:00:10  0:00:05  0:00:05     2
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
```

Why I can output to a file in the home directory, but not in the `~/.cache/mydir`.

Comment: Please edit your question with the complete command and the complete output.

Comment: What do you have for `id`, `ls -ald ~/.cache` ?

Comment: id
uid=1000(shinichi) gid=1000(shinichi) groups=1000(shinichi),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),120(lpadmin),131(lxd),132(sambashare) and ls -aid ~/.cache
10616848 /home/shinichi/.cache

Comment: What's the output of `lsattr /home/shinichi/.cache/radio_searches.json`?

Comment: $ lsattr /home/shinichi/.cache/tera/radio_searches.json
--------------e----- /home/shinichi/.cache/tera/radio_searches.json

Answer (score 2):

I use the Snap when I installed curl.

The Snap ‘home’ interface permits access only to non-hidden files and directories in a user’s /home.

```
sudo snap remove gh
sudo rm -r ~/snap/gh
```

I used apt to install curl and it is working now.

```
sudo apt install curl
```